# Multiplicative basis gets inherited for an algebra modulo a compatible ideal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, groebner-basis

Let $A$ be an associative $k$-algebra with unit.

> **Definition.**
> A set $B \subseteq A$ is called a **multiplicative basis** of $A$ if $B$ is a $k$-basis of $A$ and if $B \cup \{0\}$ is closed under multiplication, meaing $b \cdot b' \in B \cup \{0\}$ for all $b,b' \in B \cup \{0\}$.

> **Definition.**
> For a multiplicative basis $B$ of $A$, we call a two-sided ideal $I \subseteq A$ **compatible** if it is generated by elements of the form $b - b'$ for $b,b' \in B \cup \{0\}$.

Let us fix a multiplicative basis $B$ for $A$.

I would like to show the following.

> **Proposition.** Let $I \subseteq A$ be a compatible (two-sided) ideal.
>
> Then $\overline B \setminus \{ 0\} \subseteq A/I$ (the set of residue classes of $B$ without $0$) is a multiplicative basis for $A / I$.

The only thing missing for me to show this is the linear independence.
I somehow struggle to prove this, even though it seems like it should be easy to prove (although maybe tedious).

I strongly suspect this is true, because a lot of other things would make sense then.
Intuitively, it makes sense because modding out a compatible ideal basically just means that I can swap out some $b$ for a $b'$, so things won't change much, because all we are doing is identifying certain basis elements with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $\overline{B} \setminus \{0\}$ is linearly independent (over $k$). The trick is to notice that $I$ has a nice $k$-basis. First, observe that the compatibility of $I$ and the multiplicativity of $B$ imply that the set
\begin{equation*}
S = \left\{b-b' \in I: b,b' \in B \cup \{0\}\right\}
\end{equation*}
generates $I$ as a $k$-vector space. Now, let $\{b_j\}_{j \in J} \cup \{0\}$ be a set of representatives for the distinct elements of $\overline{B} \cup \{0\}$. Then we can find a subset of $S$ that is a $k$-basis for $I$, namely
\begin{equation*}
T = (B \cap I) \cup \bigcup_{j \in J}\{b_j-b \in I:b \in B, b \neq b_j\}.
\end{equation*}
Since $T \cup \{b_j\}_{j \in J}$ is still linearly independent, it follows that $\overline{B} \setminus \{0\} = \{b_j+I\}_{j \in J}$ is linearly independent as well.

Comment: Thank you very much!

I am afraid I do not understand why what you propose is a $k$-basis for $I$, and it seems like the same (or very similar) stumbling block I hit myself.  Would you mind explaining it?  I feel a little bit stupid haha.

I actually circumvented the problem in the end via categorical equivalences in my initial setting, but I am curious of this answer here!

Comment: First, $T$ still generates $I$ since $b-b' \in S$ can always be rewritten as $(r-b')-(r-b)$, where $r \in \{b_j\} \cup \{0\}$ is the representative of $b$ and $b'$ mod $I$. Next, notice that if we have elements of the form $b$, $b_j-b'$ and $b_k-b''$ in $T$ (where $j \neq k$), then $b$, $b'$ and $b''$ have to be distinct (and are different from the $b_j$'s). Therefore, if we have a linear combination of such elements that equals $0$, then the coefficients have to be $0$ simply because $B$ is a $k$-basis for $A$.

Comment: thank you very much, what was missing in my own thinking was that indeed $b'$ and $b''$ must be distinct.